# Falta la cabecera CORS angular POST

Tags: angular

Tengo un problema al hacer una llamada a mi API realizada con python en mi servicio de angular tengo lo siguiente:

```
login(usuario:UsuarioModel) {
 let json = JSON.stringify(usuario);
 let params = 'json='+json;
 let headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded});
 return this.http.post(this.urlLogin, params,{headers}).pipe
 (map(res =>
   this.saveToke(res['token']);
   return res;
 }));
}
```

Sin embargo con el postman llamo a la url y me lo saca sin problema, no se si es que postman, no necesita tener nada de CORS o que pasa...

Answer (score 1):

No sé python, pero el problema de CORS está en el backend api. Tú deberias agregar la cabecera en el backend...algo asi:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
  if environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS':
    start_response(
      '200 OK',
      [
        ('Content-Type', 'application/json'),
        ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'),
        ('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, Content-Type'),
        ('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST'),
      ]
    )
   return ''
```

Espero te ayude